# tkintertable: adding button in a row?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Is possible to add a (tkinter) button in a cell of a tkintertable ?
For example

```
from tkintertable import TableCanvas, TableModel
self.contenitore = ttk.Frame(root) 
data = {'rec1': {'col1': 99.88, 'col2': 108.79, 'label': 'rec1'},
    'rec2': {'col1': 99.88, 'col2': 321.79, 'label': 'rec3'},
    'rec3': {'col1': 29.88, 'col2': 408.79, 'label': 'rec2'}
    }
    tabella = TableCanvas(self.contenitore, data=data,editable=False)
```

can I add another column with a button for each row?

Comment: Not possible as far as I know.

Comment: Have you tried putting one in by adding instances of `Button` widgets to the rows of the `data` dictionary?

Comment: @martineau yes, it gives me error: TypeError: object of type 'Button' has no len()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it's hacky. A TableCanvas is a type of tkinter Canvas, so you can use all the tkinter Canvas methods. To add a widget such as a Button to a Canvas use the `create_window()` method.

```
tabella.update()
x1,y1,x2,y2 = tabella.getCellCoords(1,1) # place the button at cell 1, 1
btn = tk.Button(tabella, text="Hello")
tabella.create_window(((x1+x2)//2, (y1+y2)//2), window=btn)
```

You could and should use x1,y1,x2,y2 to size the button to fit perfectly on the cell.